# Facing issue with the setup Schedule My Channel Release

Tags: roku, brightscript

I tried to upload a My channel in the channel Store.

**I performed the following action:**

First, I goto => Static Analysis Tab => I performed Static analysis and clicked the run button => **I wait for 10-15 Min. It's not working**

Then, I goto => Certificate Testing => I performed Certification Testing. then goto => Static Analysis Tab => **After, It's Worked.**
Here, I'm **not found any error with static analysis**. but, In **certificate testing. it's Found two errors** like below.
[image]

1. Facing linking is not Compulsory. I guess. **Right?**
2. Channel Content Play Performance criteria are below :

   3.6 Content starts playing within 8 seconds of initiation on the Roku Streaming Stick+ (Amarillo-2019 3810X) or 10 seconds on the
   Roku Express (Littlefield 37XXX). If your channel is using the Roku
   video player, the Roku OS automatically fires beacons to measure and
   record the video start time; therefore, no additional implementation
   work for your application is required. If your channel is using a
   custom video player, your application must fire the video start
   beacons.

   For the Second Criteria, I used By Default Roku Player. So, It does not need to set any beacon at the player **Right?**

**Does anyone know Why I'm not able to setup Schedule My Channel Release? or Can anyone guide me How I Move Forward?**

Comment: Are you getting static analysis report? Is everything fine in that report?

Comment: Yes there is 2 or 3 Api related warning. But, I not found any error in static analysis. I edit my question

Comment: If there is no issue, may be you are not setting some properties properly or missing something while uploading the package for publishing.

Comment: No, I haven't forgotten anything. I don't see the button of Schedule. Maybe Channel Deep Linking and Channel Content Play Performance Block my channels. But, Deep linking is not compulsory right? and for Content Play Performance. I used by default Roku video player So, not need to set beacon right?

Comment: If you are publishing as public channel, deep linking is mandatory. And you have to signal some beacons doesn't matter whether you are using native player or not. Read the certification criteria carefully and implement what remained.

Comment: Thank you so Much. I sent a mail to Roku Partner Success regarding this issue. After, 4th day they sent a reply: "Please reupload your package". But, I didn't do anything. It's Automatically enabled